# Struts 2 cannot resolve java action method in # tag

Tags: struts2, freemarker

There's something I'm been missing in how Struts resolve ftl tag,
I have an action with some methods that I'm trying to call from my ftl.

The signature:

```
<@s.property value="%{someJavaMethod(someVariable)}>
```

is working fine, but the directive

```
<#include someJavaMethod(someOtherVariable)>
```

is giving me this:

```
----: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> someJavaMethod
```

and I cant figure out why, since, based on my limited knowledge of struts the signature `#` has access to the context `Map` where action properties and methods are stored.

NB: I checked that the problem is not in the `someJavaMethod` since debugging the code it doesn't even enter into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the action to call its method in Freemarker. It is [supported](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/freemarker-support.html) by the Struts 2 framework.

```xml
<#include action.someJavaMethod(someOtherVariable)>
```